# Android: CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException on application startup

Tags: google-fabric

We are trying to integrate Crashlytics into our android-application (armeabi-v7a). The application is written in both Java and C++, so we need native crash reporting too.

Unfortunately, we have **com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException** while launching a successful built application.

```
06-19 18:22:47.245 : ASSERTION (EXCEPTION!!!) JavaUnhandledExceptionHandler, thread: Thread[main,5,main]
06-19 18:22:47.247 : java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.organization/com.organization.ActivityName}: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException: 
06-19 18:22:47.247 : This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
06-19 18:22:47.247 : install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
06-19 18:22:47.247 : 
06-19 18:22:47.247 :    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2665)
06-19 18:22:47.247 :    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
06-19 18:22:47.247 :    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
06-19 18:22:47.247 :    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
06-19 18:22:47.247 :    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-19 18:22:47.247 :    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
06-19 18:22:47.247 :    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
06-19 18:22:47.247 :    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
06-19 18:22:47.247 :    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
06-19 18:22:47.247 :    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
06-19 18:22:47.247 : Caused by: io.fabric.sdk.android.services.concurrency.UnmetDependencyException: com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsMissingDependencyException: 
06-19 18:22:47.247 : This app relies on Crashlytics. Please sign up for access at https://fabric.io/sign_up,
06-19 18:22:47.247 : install an Android build tool and ask a team member to invite you to this app's organization.
```

Neither debug nor release have run. Could you please provide us more detailed installation guide to solve the issue? All the installation steps were performed in accordance with the docs pages:

https://fabric.io/downloads/ant

https://docs.fabric.io/android/crashlytics

- Build system: Android Ant
- OS: Mac OS X El Capitan
- Android API: 23

**The project structure is assumed to be as follows:**

- AndroidManifest.xml
- ant.properties
- assets/
- bin/
- build.xml
- cert/
- custom_rules.xml
- fabric.credentials
- fabric.properties
- kit-libs/
- kits.properties
- libs/
- local.properties
- obj/
- project.properties
- res/

**Fabric related settings:**

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<meta-data android:name="com.crashlytics.ApiKey" android:value=organizationApiSecret/>
<meta-data android:name="io.fabric.ApiKey" android:value=organizationApiKey/>
```

custom_rules.xml:

```
<import file="path/to/sdk/crashlytics/crashlytics_build.xml"/>
```

kits.properties (generated):

```
com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.5
com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-ndk:1.1.2
```

project.properties (generated):

```
manifestmerger.enabled=true
target=android-23
android.library.reference.2=kit-libs/com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics
```

fabric.properties:

```
apiSecret=organizationApiSecret
apiKey=organizationApiKey
enableNDK=true
androidNdkOut=obj
androidNdkLibsOut=libs
```

Installation steps:

1. compile c++
2. ant crashlytics-onboard
3. removing unwanted architectures: kit-libs/com-crashlytics-sdk-android_crashlytics-ndk/libs/
4. ant our_target
5. ant crashlytics-symbols

Comment: Mike from Fabric here and thanks for the detailed post. Do you have any conditional logic around when Fabric is enabled? It looks like there is a build type going on where Fabric is partially implemented.